# python keyboard : go to the top of the text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make a macro in python, that when pressed execute this folliwing script to add time before a text :

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
from datetime import *
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(0.2)
    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F12'):
            now = datetime.now()
            keyboard.press_and_release('Home')
            keyboard.write(f"{now.hour}h{now.minute}m{now.second}s :")
            keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')

    except :
        pass
```

Its work well until I send a message that make multiple lines ! How to solve the issue ?

1 line message :

`hello` -> press F12 -> send `15h45h07s : hello`

multiple lines :

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

-> press F12

send :

````
line 1
line 2
15h46m30s : line 3```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the top of the page using Ctrl+Home, so here is the improved code:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
from datetime import *
from time import sleep

while True:
    sleep(0.2)
    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F12'):
            now = datetime.now()
            keyboard.press_and_release('Ctrl+Home')
            keyboard.write(f"{now.hour}h{now.minute}m{now.second}s :")
            keyboard.press_and_release('End')
            keyboard.press_and_release('Down')

    except :
        pass
```

However, this will ONLY insert the time at the top of the file, and not for any subsequent lines. If you want to use this to do multiple lines, maybe think of a more complicated approach, where you perhaps store a list of lines which have the time before them, and another key to clear this list. Here is my example:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
from datetime import *
from time import sleep

lines = []

while True:
    sleep(0.2)
    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F12'):
            now = datetime.now()
            if len(lines) == 0:
                keyboard.press_and_release('Ctrl+Home')
            else:
                keyboard.press_and_release('Home')
            keyboard.write(f"{now.hour}h{now.minute}m{now.second}s :")
            keyboard.press_and_release('End')
            keyboard.press_and_release('Down')
            lines.append("placeholder")

    except :
        pass

    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F11'):
            lines = []

    except :
        pass
```

P.S. I edited your code so that rather than adding an enter at the end, it goes down a line. This is better for doing multiple lines, as it removes unwanted whitespace.

Example:
[image: Example]

Comment: woah you're a genious